# 'Equal to' if statement failing on variable from PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, pdo

I am trying to see if a code stored in my database is the same as the one the user provides, currently

user would provide the vCode via POST but i have it set to what it actually is for testing purposes
`$vCode = "69582";`

Now i'm using a PDO query to get the vCode that's in the database.

```
$dsn1 = "mysql:dbname={$this->dbDatabaseName};host={$this->dbHostname};";
            $conn1 = new PDO($dsn1, $this->user, $this->password);
            $conn1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `accinfo` WHERE Email = :email AND vCode = :vCode";
        $stmt1 = $conn1->prepare($sql1);
        $stmt1->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt1->bindParam(':vCode', $vCode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt1->execute();
            if( $stmt1->rowCount() > 0 ) {

             $result = $stmt1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
             foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt1->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
             $actualVCode = $v;
             }
```

Then i see if the vCode i got from the database ($actualVCode) is equal to the $vCode

```
              if ( $actualVCode == $vCode ){
              echo "match";
              }
```

The value stored in my database is a string and is 69582, but whenever i compare them like i do above, the if statement never comes back as true. But when i echo both $vCode and $actualVCode, they both are 69582.

Comment: 1) That's not how you use prepared statements, replace the variables with parameters and bind them afterwards 2) Just because `$actualVCode` echoes what you expect doesn't mean it actually compares to true. For all I can see it could be an instance of a class and just have a `__toString` method that outputs what you expect. What does `var_dump` on the 2 values return?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that i had to bind parameters like that, still getting used to php. I knew i had to bind parameters when using a sql insert query but not when selecting. I changed the sql query as follows

Comment: $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `accinfo` WHERE Email = :email AND vCode = :vCode";
            $stmt1 = $conn1->prepare($sql1);
            $stmt1->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt1->bindParam(':vCode', $vCode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt1->execute();

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the result from the first query and checking the result with the vCode, i've modified the query to select the whole row only if the email AND the vCode matches

```
 $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `accinfo` WHERE Email = '$email' AND vCode = '$vCode'";
    $stmt1 = $conn1->prepare($sql1);
    $stmt1->execute();
    if( $stmt1->rowCount() > 0 ) {
    //found match
    echo "found match";
    }
```